# Riddle I have no idea: "One for the front / Two for the back ..."

Tags: riddle

One for the front
Two for the back
You will never need three.
What is this?

I thought it might be personality.

Comment: Just to clarify, _I thought it might be personality._ is not part of the riddle right? :P

Comment: To add more to DrunkWolf's question, does this mean you don't know the answer?

Comment: Rolled back because I'm unsure whether the edit removes important information, and would rather leave it to OP to decide.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is:

> Mirror

(one to see your front; two to see your back; you never need three)

Comment: [Possible counter-example](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/full-size-3-panel-dressing-mirror-screen/1041964637) ;-)

Comment: http://www.thekaleidoscopebook.com/thescopebook/scope-resources/kaleidoscope-mirror-systems?showall=&start=3

Comment: There've been more than a few times when trying to look at something in an awkward location that I've wished for a 3rd hand to hold another one.

Comment: [A definite counter-example!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector#Corner_reflector) There are other ways to make retroreflectors, but three mirrors is really neat. That's not to say that this isn't the answer.

Answer (score 12):

> It's the letter 'o'.
> At the front of '**o**ne', at the back of 'tw**o**' and none in 'three'.

Comment: Clever, but I think it would be "you'll never need *it for* three" - the way it's written now, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 8):

This is

> a tricycle. 1 wheel in front, two in back. You would never need three wheels in either position.

Comment: What do they call those things that have 2 wheels in the front and 1 in the back?

Comment: @JohnOdom https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricycle according to wikipedia it's called a tadpole tricycle. The more common example I references being called a delta tricycle.

Answer (score 6):

Potential answer:

> http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/number-one <-- see the first example, don't need a 3.

Comment: Might be a good idea to edit that information into your answer. Currently it's link-only.

Comment: I think the answerer is shy of incorporating the explicit answer into the question because it is, hm, not really decent =)

Comment: Yeah I thought at first it probably wasn't the intended answer anyway but now I'm starting to think it may be. I'll delinkify it if that turns out to be the case =)